# Can Google Calendar API be used to create scalable scheduling service?

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-calendar-api

I need to create a scheduler for my own SaaS, and I'm trying to understand whether Google Calendar API is a fit for that. Basically I could have hundreds of thousands of calendars. Each calendar may be a user of my service, but not a Google user. It seems that perhaps I could use resource calendars under my Google Cloud service account. My biggest concern is whether my usage will fall within the Calendar API's service quotas, either automatically or by requesting a quota increase?

Comment: Google Calendar is tied directly to Google Account identities. To use this service outside of that use case (bypassing OAuth 2.0) probably violates terms of service.

Answer (score 1):

Yes service accounts will fall within quota usage limits.  There is also a limit about creating more then 25 calendars in a day causing the user to end up in read mode for the rest of the day.

[pricing](https://developers.google.com/calendar/pricing)

> **Google Calendar API Usage Limits**
>
> The Google Calendar API has a courtesy limit of 1,000,000 queries per day.
>
> To view or change usage limits for your project, or to request an increase to your quota, do the following:
>
> 1. If you don't already have a billing account for your project, then create one.
> 2. Visit the Enabled APIs page of the API library in the API Console, and select an API from the list.
> 3. To view and change quota-related settings, select Quotas. To view usage statistics, select Usage.

Comment: Thanks @DalmTo. What I'm not clear is whether Google will increase these limits if I request them to, and whether my use case is even something Google wants to support? It seems that the API might be more geared toward Google users on the front-end.

Comment: I think it's a valid use case.   just apply for the extension early it can take a while to be approved

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, you could work around the quota issues by sharding your users across multiple Service Accounts. You would probably also want to shard them across multiple App IDs.

On the other hand, don't do it. In my experience, using Google APIs outside their intended use case doesn't end well.

Comment: Yeah, I prefer to work within SLA's. It's too risky otherwise.